# Django-Oscar tutorial 'deploy/solr' file not found error?

Tags: solr, django-oscar

[Django-Oscar tutorial](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html).

It uses Solr.  In the tutorial above there is a link to the [Solr installation guide](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_setup_solr.html).

In the Solr guide, this is the line where I am stuck at:

```
ln -s <your_oscar_checkout>/sites/<sandbox|demo>/deploy/solr conf
```

That line gives me the error:

```
bash: /deploy/solr: No such file or directory
bash: your_oscar_checkout: No such file or directory
```

I tried searching for a solution but I couldn't find anything about those missing folders.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
ln -s <your_oscar_checkout>/sites/<sandbox|demo>/deploy/solr conf
```

Essentially you are creating a link of `solr` directory from your oscar checkout to `conf` directory under `solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1`. Please check you have the correct replacement for `<your_oscar_checkout>` directory and `<sandbox|demo>`, which is why it has been put in angel bracket. Otherwise you can copy the content to `solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf` path. But then if you need to update any properties for schema then you do it here not in `oscar` directory. Then just start the solr using `java -jar solr-4.7.2/example/start.jar`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having a problem with the `<your_oscar_checkout>` part. Is it going to be the path to the folder like `/home/user/django-oscar` or path to a specific file?